# Invalid header name in HTTP request

Tags: c++, c, http-headers, http-post

I'm manually making the following request using sockets in C++.

```
struct addrinfo hints, *res;
int sockfd;

char buf[2056];
int byte_count;

//get host info, make socket and connect it
memset(&hints, 0,sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
getaddrinfo("some_web_service.azurewebsites.net","80", &hints, &res);
sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);

char *header = "POST /api/factura HTTP/1.1\n"
"Host: some_web_service.azurewebsites.net\n"
"Content-Type: application/json\n"
"Accept: */*\n"
"Cache-Control: no-cache\n"
"Content-Length: 1188\n"
"{\"IdTransaccion\": \"6828836174244758\",\"InstitucionFinanciera\": \"Banco Azteca\",\"NumTarjeta\": \"0077\",\"Fecha\":\"2019-10-06T17:00:00\",\"SubTotal\": \"2000.00\",\"Moneda\": \"MXN\",\"Total\": \"2320.00\",\"TipoDeComprobante\": \"I\",\"FormaPago\": \"01\",\"MetodoPago\": \"PUE\",\"LugarExpedicion\": \"06300\",\"Emisor\": {\"Rfc\": \"LAN8507268IA\",\"Nombre\": \"Banco Azteca, S.A de C.V.\",\"RegimenFiscal\": \"601\"},\"Receptor\": {\"Rfc\": \"VEV0603275K9\",\"Nombre\": \"Test Receptor\",\"UsoCFDI\": \"G03\"},\"Conceptos\":{\"Concepto\":[{\"ClaveProdServ\":\"84111506\",\"ClaveUnidad\":\"E48\",\"Cantidad\":\"1\",\"Descripcion\":\"Producto1\",\"ValorUnitario\":\"1000.00\",\"Importe\":\"1000.00\",\"Impuestos\":{\"Traslados\":{\"Traslado\":{\"Base\":\"1000.00\",\"Impuesto\":\"002\",\"TipoFactor\":\"Tasa\",\"TasaOCuota\":\"0.160000\",\"Importe\":\"160.00\"}}}},{\"ClaveProdServ\":\"01010101\",\"ClaveUnidad\":\"E48\",\"Cantidad\":\"1\",\"Descripcion\":\"Producto2\",\"ValorUnitario\":\"1000.00\",\"Importe\":\"1000.00\",\"Impuestos\":{\"Traslados\":{\"Traslado\":{\"Base\":\"1000.00\",\"Impuesto\":\"002\",\"TipoFactor\":\"Tasa\",\"TasaOCuota\":\"0.160000\",\"Importe\":\"160.00\"}}}}]},\"Impuestos\":{\"TotalImpuestosTrasladados\":\"320.00\",\"Traslados\": {\"Traslado\": {\"Impuesto\": \"002\",\"TipoFactor\": \"Tasa\",\"TasaOCuota\": \"0.160000\",\"Importe\": \"320.00\"}}}}\n";

send(sockfd,header,strlen(header),0);

//all right ! now that we're connected, we can receive some data!
byte_count = recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
byte_count = recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
```

But the message received is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Date: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 21:34:20 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 339

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my headers? I already tried using `\r\n` instead of `\n` but that doesn't seem to do nothing.

Comment: Use "\r\n" instead of "\n". End last header with "\r\n\r\n". In any case, I'd advise using some well-tested library.

Comment: I want to but this is an ARM device, I'm cross compiling with Windows 7, I tried searching the curl library for ARM ABI HF compiler but couldnt properly link it. Might have to open a new question about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're missing an empty line between your headers and message body. Per the RFC (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4):

> Request (section 5) and Response (section 6) messages use the generic
>   message format of RFC 822 [9] for transferring entities (the payload
>   of the message). Both types of message consist of a start-line, zero
>   or more header fields (also known as "headers"), an empty line (i.e.,
>   a line with nothing preceding the CRLF) indicating the end of the
>   header fields, and possibly a message-body.

Try adding an extra `\n` after your last header line:

```
"Content-Length: 1188\n\n"
```

To ensure compatibility with applications that adhere strictly to the RFC, you should use `\r\n` (CRLF) as mentioned in the quote!

Comment: Also, HTTP *requires* `\r\n` for line breaks, not `\n`

Comment: Changed everything to \r\n and added the extra line and now it works, now I'm getting a 500 internal server error but that must be out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Required by RFC, but not in practice. I think it's often given a pass. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.3